# Customizing HTML snippet in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

If I have a HTML Snippet as below, how do I get the required output as below in python.

## Sample HTML snippet:

```
<td width="10" class="data1"><a class="datalink" href="m01_detail.asp?key=002396653&amp;itemNumber=0">&gt;</a></td>

          <td class="data1"><a class="datalink" href="m01_detail.asp?key=002396653&amp;itemNumber=0">002396653</a></td>

          <td class="data1">IMPORT EXPRESS RECYCLE</td>

          <td class="data1">961879066</td>

        <td class="data1">11/23/2016</td>  

          <td class="data1"></td>        <!--SARA-->

          <td class="data1" align="center">CN</td>

          <td class="data1" align="center">PVG</td>
```

## Output:

961879066|CN

## My Code so far:

```
    def reading():
    with open("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\test.txt") as f:
        for lines in f.readlines():
            line = lines.replace("\t","").strip()
            print (line)

    f.close()

    reading()
```

Thanks,

Comment: You should use beautifulsoup to parse html contents... Btw, it would help if you post the website link that you're trying to scrape. You can use `soup.find_all('td', {'class':'data1'})`, to get all `td` tags with the `class` attribute equal to `data1`, for example.

Comment: I agree with @dot.Py that we need the link (or the complete HTML page). Would I be correct in thinking that you want the texts of the fourth and sixth `td` tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to get required output:

```
import lxml.html

html = lxml.html.fromstring("""<td width="10" class="data1"><a class="datalink" href="m01_detail.asp?key=002396653&amp;itemNumber=0">&gt;</a></td>
<td class="data1"><a class="datalink" href="m01_detail.asp?key=002396653&amp;itemNumber=0">002396653</a></td>
<td class="data1">IMPORT EXPRESS RECYCLE</td>
<td class="data1">961879066</td>
<td class="data1">11/23/2016</td>
<td class="data1"></td>        <!--SARA-->
<td class="data1" align="center">CN</td>
<td class="data1" align="center">PVG</td>""")

output = html.xpath('concat(//td[4], "|", //td[7])')
print(output)  # '961879066|CN'
```

*Pass original `HTML` code to `html` variable*